# Заполнение списка listView в Android 5

Tags: java, android

С помощью адаптера заполняю список:

```
public class MainListViewArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Article> {
    Context context;
    ArrayList<Article> results;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ImageLoader imageLoader;

    private ImageLoadingListener animateFirstListener = new AnimateFirstDisplayListener();

    private DisplayImageOptions options;

    public MainListViewArrayAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<Article> results){
        super(context, R.layout.item_main,results);
        this.context = context;
        this.results = results;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .showImageOnLoading(R.color.white)
                .cacheInMemory(true)
                .cacheOnDisk(true)
                .considerExifParams(true).build();
    }

    static class ViewHolder{
        public ImageView prevewImageView;
        public TextView authorTextView;
        public TextView headerTextView;
        public TextView dateTextView;
        public ImageView verticalDividerImageView;

        public void SetPreviewImageViewVisibility(){
            prevewImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final Article result = results.get(position);

        View rootView = convertView;
        final ViewHolder viewHolder;

        if (rootView == null) {
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_main, null);
            // configure view holder
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.prevewImageView = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.prevewImageView);
            viewHolder.authorTextView = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.authorTextView);
            viewHolder.headerTextView = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.headerTexView);
            viewHolder.dateTextView = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.dateTextView);
            viewHolder.verticalDividerImageView = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.verticalDividerImageView);

            Typeface mediumTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"AvenirNextCyr-Medium.otf");
            Typeface regularTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"AvenirNextCyr-Regular.otf");

            viewHolder.headerTextView.setTypeface(mediumTypeface);
            viewHolder.authorTextView.setTypeface(regularTypeface);
            viewHolder.dateTextView.setTypeface(regularTypeface);

            rootView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }else{
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) rootView.getTag();
        }





        if (result.title != null){
            viewHolder.headerTextView.setText(result.title);
        }
        if (result.date != null){
            viewHolder.dateTextView.setText(Utils.streamToDate(result.date));
        }
        if (result.author != null && result.author.length > 0){
            viewHolder.authorTextView.setText(result.author[0].author);
        }else if(result.author_string != null){
            viewHolder.authorTextView.setText(result.author_string);
        }

        if (result.previewUrl != null){
            if (imageLoader == null){
                imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
                imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(context));
            }
            imageLoader.displayImage(result.previewUrl, viewHolder.prevewImageView,options,animateFirstListener);

            if (result.previewUrl.length() == 0){
                viewHolder.prevewImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }else{
                viewHolder.prevewImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }

        rootView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context,ArticleActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("id",result.id);
                intent.putExtra("type",result.materialType);
                intent.putExtra("title",result.title);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


        return rootView;


    }

//    public void setOnArticleSelected(IAction<Article> listener){
//        this.articleSelectedListener = listener;
//    }
//
//    public void OnArticleSelected(final Article selected){
//        if(this.articleSelectedListener != null)
//            this.articleSelectedListener.Invoke(selected);
//    }
//
//    private IAction<Article> articleSelectedListener;


    private static class AnimateFirstDisplayListener extends SimpleImageLoadingListener {

        static final List<String> displayedImages = Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList<String>());

        @Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
            if (loadedImage != null) {
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view;
                boolean firstDisplay = !displayedImages.contains(imageUri);
                if (firstDisplay) {
                    FadeInBitmapDisplayer.animate(imageView, 500);
                    displayedImages.add(imageUri);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

На Android 4 с кодом никаких проблем. Начала тестировать на эмуляторе Android 5. Почему-то список картинками заполняется, а текст не виден. Кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой?

Сейчас в XML попробовала написать текст в `textview` - тоже не видно. Работаю в студии. С чем может быть связана проблема?

Ещё раз повторюсь, что на устройствах всё в норме. Но все устройства на Android 4.

Comment: цвет фона совпадает с цветом текста, например

Comment: Вероятно проблема со стилями. Может текст белый на белом фоне?

Comment: цвет фона светлый, цвет текста тёмный) не ясно мне совсем, что за дела